# RabbitMQ c# client: utilize all cpu cores

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I am testing some things with .net core and rabbitMQ client. One service will publish some million rows of data, and another service will receive and parse those. Each row may take 4-10secs of parsing.
So the point is

1) Be able to utilize more machines to run the receiving service, and

2) Utilize all cpu cores of the machine the service runs at.

So 1 seems quite obvious. Use more servers to parse more messages from the queues. But I cannot figure how to do the second.

I wrote a simple .net core program assuming I want to utilize 3 cores:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello1",
                                     durable: true,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);

                var tasks = new List<Task>() {
                    ReceiveEvent(channel, 1),
                    ReceiveEvent(channel, 2),
                    ReceiveEvent(channel, 3)
                };

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                //
                channel.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private static async Task ReceiveEvent(IModel channel, int consumerNo)
        {            
            var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            int i = 1;
            consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received {i++} lines in consumer {consumerNo} --- {message}");
                Thread.Sleep(500 * consumerNo);
                //
                channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                await Task.Yield();
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello1",
                                 autoAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);
        }
```

No matter how many times I ran it, only consumer number 1 is catching the events. Do I need to make such calls line Task.WhenAll? Or does .net core runtime, utilizes all cpu cores if the events are fired async?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From my Experience with RabbitMQ, When Ever a message is received one thread of message listner is created. While process this message, queue is not push another message to the listner. In your case, you have to first receive the message and than you can process in multiple thread.